# Angular free text datepicker that will auto populate slashes(MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

I'm using the datepicker (ng-bootstrap) in a popup, I want this field also allow user to insert date manually (`MM/DD/YYYY`) but instead of asking user for entering slash it should auto populate slash.

Angular 8 and `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, I wrote a handler on keyup event trying to append slash and setting the values to form but it is not allowing me, I've tried removing the validator on form-control so validation happen only after user enter date completely rather than partial input.

I have created handler on keyup event

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="displayFieldStyle(form,'abc')">
<div class="input-group">
    <input formControlName="abc" class="form-control" ngbDatepicker 
    #abc="ngbDatepicker" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" 
    minlength="10" maxlength="10" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" 
    (keyup)="onKeyEventHandler($event)" />

    <div class="input-group-append" (click)="abc.toggle()">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> 
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


this.memberLookupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
...
...
abc: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
             DateValidator.checkDateFormat])],
...
...
});


onKeyEventHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (event.which !== 191 ) {
      let currentValue= this.form.get('abc').value;
      if(!(currentValue == "" || currentValue == null)){
        let numChars = currentValue.length;
        if(numChars === 2 || numChars === 5){
          currentValue = currentValue+'/';
          this.form.get('abc').setValidators(null);
          this.form.controls['abc'].setValue(currentValue);
          this.form.get('abc').updateValueAndValidity();
        }
      }
   }
}



const value = c.value;
let match;
const datePattern = /^([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{4})$/;
if (value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        match = value.match(datePattern);
        if (!match) {
            return {'invalidDateFormat': true};
        }
    }
}
```

but form value resetting after two entering values that `12` resetting to "" (empty), but var in component have value `12/`.

I want to auto populate slash for date field (`MM/DD/YYYY`) => after user enters two values and four values example that is `12` make it to `12/` then user proceed to `12/20` make it to `12/20/` user continue to `12/20/2019`.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, I guess its setting the value to empty because the form became invalid

Comment: Datepickers usually come with a configuration to set date format, check the docs for any.

Comment: @GaryB how to avoid form invalid check for temporarily and add it after completing user input

Answer (score 0):

To do setValue or patchvalue the format must be json with date month and year not string, that is why it is getting empty.

eg :

```
this.form.controls['abc'].setValue({
        day: 20,
        month: 4,
        year: 1969
     });
```

We can do that by using directives and host listener

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.appMaskValue && (this.appMaskValue.length === 2 || this.appMaskValue.length === 5) && event.key !== 'Backspace') {
      this.renderer.setProperty(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'value', this.appMaskValue + '/');
    }
  }
}
```

you can find the details in
https://medium.com/@victor.loh95/create-date-masking-custom-directive-for-ngbdatepicker-ff4cc73097c1